# Expand tableHeaderView as UITableView scrolls like Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, twitter

I'm trying to expand UITableView's tableHeaderView like how Twitter does it (well more like how they used to do it).  As I was messing with it, I happened to implement -scrollViewDidScroll like this:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
         float offsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
         CGRect tblFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
         [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
         self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(tblFrame.origin.x, offsetY, tblFrame.size.width, originalHeaderHeight-offsetY);
     }
 }
```

and it works almost exactly how I wanted it to.  I went back to clean it up, and I took the `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` out, and it stopped working.

When I take out `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  tableHeaderView's y origin does not get changed, so it expands, but it does not stay at the top of the view.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hmmm.... it's strange that the line you took out would make it work in the first place. What do you mean by "almost exactly how I wanted"? What is different from the way the old Twitter app worked (I don't have that one to look at it)?

Comment: It is strange.  I was just messing with it for a while and didn't realize I had that in there, then I went back to clean up and it stopped working.
The new Twitter app stretches the navigation bar.  The old one stretched the top cell, or maybe tableHeaderView.

"Almost exactly" because if I slide down the table and that first cell goes out of view then it will go back to not adjusting the y origin.

Comment: You can replace that line with [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded], and that will make it work also. I presume that calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: is causing the table view to call that method.